# Can't generate allure report from jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, allure

I'm trying to generate allure report in jenkins. Allure reports are generated fine when doing it from freestyle project and setting up allure in post build actions - report can be opened from jenkins build page. However when trying to do same in pipeline getting

```
java.io.IOException: Can't find allure commandline <null>
```

Tried to use command from Jenkins snippet generator:

```
allure([includeProperties: false, jdk: '', properties: [], reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS', results: [[path: 'allure-results']]])
```

could someone advise?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Allure plug-in for Jenkins? If not here is a guide that might help you [how to automate testing using selenium, webdriver, jenkins and Allure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-automate-testing-using-selenium-webdriver-jenkins-and-allure)

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be fixed in Allure Jenkins Plugin 2.15